# Is it possible to command an engine to run at a fixed RPM while in Park using a scan tool?

Tags: scan-tool

I have a bi-directional scan tool I used on a 2002 Chevy S10 to relearn a new crank position sensor and to do a ABS bleed. Next thing I'm planning to do is to run an induction cleaner like a SeaFoam product through the intake. Instructions on these spray cleaners typically say to run the engine about 1000 RPM above target idle while spraying. This clearly makes it a two-person job, but I'm wondering if its possible for a bi-directional scan tool to command the engine to run at a fixed RPM so I could run the spray cleaner without pedal intervention. Still looking for such a feature on this Autel I have.

I understand newer cars with electronically controlled throttle plates may have such a thing, but I partially doubt it on a 2002 Chevy with the old-school pull-cable. I thought it might be possible using the cruise control module which is electronically controlled.

(Alternatively I could just hold the throttle plate at a fixed position with one hand and the spray cleaner with the other. I was just looking for an option that doesn't involved me leaning over the drive belt and clutch fan on a hot, running engine.)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! As far as regular scan tools go, no, you can't do this. Someone could design a tool to do this through the interface, though. In general, scan tools are used to do just that "scan" the ECU to see if there are any issues as well as to get live data. This is more of a passive roll. What you are talking about is an active roll, which usually isn't the case. Does someone sell a tool to do this? Most likely, but it wouldn't be classified as a "scan tool".

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to buy a tool (about $40) that will attach to the steering wheel and hold down your accelerator pedal. This one screws in and out to set the length making it very easy to set to a specific RPM. This will accomplish what you are trying to do and is much cheaper then a scan tool.

[image]